Alternatives to backup/restore databases for testing purposes
I have an environment for testing purposes with its own database (Microsoft Azure). So every single release, once we deploy a new version to our environment, we restore the database from our backup. And that restore process takes for ages. Do we have any alternatives to full restore? Since we create tons of junk data because of our automated tests, we need to have a 'fresh' database once we moved to a new version. I know that it's a good practice to have some 'tear down' mechanism, but our tests create literally huge amount of data, so we thought that backup/restore is the only one smart way to handle our issue. But since the restore can take, let's say 5-6 hours, we are searching for alternatives.

Could you please provide your approach?

For now my approach is simple - just to back up and restore the entire data base, and this method as I mentioned above takes too long

Restoring a full database for each test deployment can be time-consuming, especially if you are dealing with large amounts of data. to reduce this time, you can follow below approaches:

Instead of getting a full restore, you can truncate all test tables and reset database objects to their original state. This approach works well if you only need to back up your n=original data do not test data and clean up junk data generated by tests

TRUNCATE TABLE TestTable1;



You can use Hyperscale service tier which provides Fast database backups regardless of size and Fast database restores in minutes rather than hours or days.


As I understand 'TRUNCATE TABLE TestTable1' removes all rows from the table, but the issue is I don't need to delete all the rows, I want to keep some of them, so I want to remove only the rows which are being created by my tests. Besides some of my tests don't create, but just modify some rows so I want to somehow revert those updates after the tests are done

Add a TestRunID column to mark test data inserted and delete rows after tests and create the temporary table form original data and then after running test restore the original data from temporary table. you can try this approcah

Can you please provide more details ? Ok, I got the idea of inserting data and then deleting the rows where I have TestRunID. But how can I use temporary tables, I mean how can I use the to restore data ?
